# no output on stereo

Tags: output, short-circuit, stereo

My stereo sometimes taking a break from playing on left channel.
If I turn it off for a second and turn back on again it will play for less then a second and then will stop playing on left channel again.
I also gave it a few days without being connected to any power source, after I plugged everything in, it worked for an hour.

What may cause it? overheating? dust? short circuit?

Thanks!

Comment: You have followed a logical process.  Leave it to cool and it works.  You have also listed possible suspects.  What do you have to do now to eliminate your possibilities.  Dust is a typical problem with any electronics.

Comment: Check your connections on the speakers.  Are they banana plug type?   If they are, they may need tightening up.   Check all connections though.  I know this sounds obvious, but we've all been there at one time or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly have an intermittent connection somewhere in your stereo which is temperature sensitive. When it warms up the materials shift just enough to open up the connection. The approach to use is to open up the stereo and just start poking around with something non-conductive, like a finger or the eraser end of a pencil. When you find the spot where a touch either causes or fixes your problem, this is the likely culprit. This might be a solder joint, or it could be a hairline crack in a PC trace, or (very unlikely) a cracked component. Flex your wire harnesses, too - you might have a flakey connection on either the front or back panel. Then you fix it.